# How do I know if the network im inside allows me to use ssh?

Tags: ssh

I'm in the university, trying to logging to ssh to a server that has ssh working outside the university network, but I can't login. How do I know if ssh is enable or not?

But I know that server is not configured correctly. so in order to remove some uncertainty. I want to know if there is a command to check if University has blocked ssh or not.

Comment: Try ssh'ing from another source network or to a different exernal host?  E.g.: ssh -vT git@github.com

Comment: Try asking your university IT department!

Comment: Try adding "-v" (verbose debug mode) as your first parameter.  Apparently ssh is not blocked at this new Starbucks, but maybe the connection is just terrible. I suspected ssh was blocked because I couldn't edit a file through sshfs. Perfectly valid question, I've been doing this for 32 years! What's the point of Server Fault if you can't ask dumb questions? Before you get high and mighty deciding what is "professional," remember the founders of Google did not even know HTML, hence the sparse homepage design--true story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple test would be to `telnet $ssh-host $ssh-port`. You should see something like the following almost immediately if it worked:

$ telnet sshserver.example.com ssh
Trying 1.2.3.4...
Connected to sshserver.example.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5

If it takes a while or you get an abrupt failure then it is either not running on the remote server, or you got the port wrong, or it is blocked somewhere between the shell you're running and the remote sshd.

Update based on your answers:
The problem is probably not your university network. Most likely (hopefully) you have something sitting between your home desktop and your ISP (ie your router or WiFi AP etc). That device does not know that you want to allow the inbound SSH connections from the internet. You want to:
1 add a TCP forwarding rule to route an inbound TCP port to a pre-defined destination (your desktop's IP address at port 22). I *strongly* suggest you pick a big number (larger than 1024 but smaller than 65535) as the port. Your rule will look something like "forward from inbound port 3299 to desk_top_ip port 22"
2 When you are not at home and using your laptop you will have to ssh to your public IP address (not the same as your desktop IP address). You can find your public IP most easily by going to a site like http://whatismyipaddress.com/. It probably doesn't change very often.
3 When you are not at home and using your laptop you will have to ssh to the TCP port you specified above (not the default ssh port of 22). So your ssh command, if you use a command line, would look like `ssh my_user_name@my_public_ip_at_home -p 3288`

enjoy

Comment: Judging from your answer it means there is no direct command to check if ssh is enabled in the network I'm currently in. Say (McDonlads wifi network). But thanks for the commands. Learned a new thing

Comment: There is a direct way. The direct way to do it is to inspect the router and firewall configurations that are managed by your university and ISP. Do you prefer the direct way or the easy way :)

Comment: lol, ofcourse easy way. But problem is, My server can accept ssh locally but I can't ssh externally. When I asked in superuser they told me its the ISP that has disabled ssh feature for me. When I called them they said they didn't. Now the only place I have access to internet is the University. And since I can't ssh from Uni. I'm confused between 3 things. my ISP is lying, Uni disabled ssh, or my server is not configured correctly.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by this: "My server can accept ssh locally but I can't ssh externally". Do you control the SSH server? Can you ever connect to the SSH server (meaning from a network other than your university)?

Comment: I mean, When I'm home. I can ssh from my laptop to my desktop. But when I go to the University. I can't ssh to my desktop. Sorry if I was confusing

Comment: Chances are you're actually trying to SSH into your router, not your desktop.